# How to get started in modeling vortices?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

I have a scenario where I need to computationally model vortices for a project and I'd like to understand this mathematically so that I can implement the code properly.

Where would one get started on such a topic at an introductory level?  I've been away from advanced calculus for about 10 years, but should be able to get back into it fairly quickly if I can find a solid starting point.

Comment: Take a look here to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex

You'll be focusing on the curl/circulation in vector fields (2D,3D).